# Which country has been credited with the most regime changes, by historians, since 1900?

Tags: political-history, international-relations, diplomacy

I recently discussed with an acquaintance of mine about the Russian interference in the USA presidential elections of 2016. Our discussion was more focus on the IT aspects of the saga but at one point during the discussion he stated that since the beginning of the previous century, the USA has been involved in more [regime change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regime_change) than any other country in the world. Following this I decided to gather information to confirm/refute this and I rapidly found [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_involvement_in_regime_change). I was aware of the most notable regime changes like the [1953 Iranian coup d'état](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Iranian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat), the [1973 Chilean coup d'état](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973_Chilean_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat) but I was surprised to find 80 entries since 1900. On the Russia side, [the list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia_involvement_in_regime_change) contains 44 entries since 1900 which is still a high number but it is nearly twice less compare to the USA over the same period. I went rapidly through both articles and the sources mentioned seem correct. I'm lacking information regarding other countries like colonial states for example (UK or France to name few). They can be good candidates like illustrated in [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18803/has-britain-invaded-most-countries-in-the-world) but I'm completely ignorant regarding this aspect of history. So here is the point that needs to be assessed :

**Have the USA been involved in more regime change than any other country in the world since 1900 ?**

To answer the question I think that the following scope is nice : both overt and covert actions aimed at altering, replacing, or preserving foreign governments.

Comment: No.  That would presumably be the UK, and the break-up of the British Empire in the aftermath of WW2.  The regime in each former colony and protectorate changed from the colonial administration to an independent government.

Comment: A lot of the entries on those lists appear rather ridiculous, for instance it says the US was involved in regime change in Honduras in 2009 because it... didn't intervene to stop a coup? That sounds absurd. Is that actually what you are interested in by "involved in regime change" or did you actually mean to ask about *causing regime changes*, which is what people usually try to imply? I think the latter would work for History.SE and have edited the topic accordingly.

Comment: I'm going to coin a term  - _covert wicked_ for this type of question.  Like most [wicked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_problem) questions, the assumptions you make about the problem determine the solution. Identifying, defining and defending the assumptions probably escalates the answer to book length.

Comment: Aside "What is the consensus of historians on… (this picture of my goldfish)?
If there is in fact a secret cabal of historians that dictates opinions on history, nobody has informed me of it. "

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I apologise for the oversight.  I shall nominate you for membership immediately!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @sempaiscuba! Now I'll never see my family again because I saw you leak a secret.